# What is the status of toastr.options.target and the functionality it targets?

Tags: toastr

I need to place the toastr inside a specific container, but I can't find this concept represented in the API. I found an old [question](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr/issues/161) where it was mentioned that `options` has an undocumented property `target` that do seem to work properly, the question was closed, referenced generally to stackoverflow and the property is still undocumented.

I'm using typescript and the typings for toastr, so the fact that `target` does not exist in `ToastrOptions` becomes very explicit.

While it would be trivial to hack around this or just to get rid of the errors in typescript, I'd like to stay clean and would appreciate some clarity on the lack of this feature or the lack of documentation.

Is `target` supposed to be documented or is the lack of support for placing the toastr in a specific container a conscious design choice?

Comment: I am confused by this as well. When I put an non-existing target as options no toasts will appear. And when I use a proper id the post apears normally relative to the body not the container specified. Or am I getting the purpose of target wrong?

Comment: @PaulWürtz As far as I remember, it will place the  markup for the notifications within target. But you probably need to make the container position relative or absolute to make the notifications adhere to the bounds of the container and not the body.

Comment: You were perfectly right. The markup is placed within the target and the change in style made everything as it should. Thanks a lot!